# Simple interest

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, percentages, word-problem

I found this problem while helping my nephew with his "O" level mathematics. My solution doesn't match the answer. Can anybody point out the error in my procedure?

> A woman buys a house valued at $\$18000$. She pays $30\%$ of its value immediately, $\$6000$ eighteen months later and the remainder after a further eighteen months. Simple interest is charged at $4.5\%$ per annum. Find how much she pays altogether?

My solution$$18000+(12600 \times 0.045 \times 1.5)+(6600 \times 0.045 \times 1.5) = 19296$$ does not match the answer. The answer given is $\$19350$.

Comment: Perhaps the answer given in the book is wrong. The book answer would be correct for a problem in which the payments were $5000, $6000, and $7000 plus accumulated interest instead of $5400, $6000 and $6600 plus accumulated interest. So one explanation would be that the $5000 initial payment was changed to 30% at some time after the answers were computed for the original version, and the answer did not get updated.

Comment: Thank you sir, I am sending an email to the publication of the book :)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the answer in the book is incorrect.  As Dilip Sarwate pointed out in the comments:

> Perhaps the answer given in the book is wrong. The book answer would be correct for a problem in which the payments were $5000,6000$, and $7000$ plus accumulated interest instead of $5400, 6000$ and $6600$ plus accumulated interest. So one explanation would be that the $5000$ initial payment was changed to $30\%$ at some time after the answers were computed for the original version, and the answer did not get updated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the answer calculated by you is correct , a reverse calculation can prove it true.